# RESTEasy and Wildfly returns 405 or 404 on requests

Tags: java, maven, jax-rs, wildfly, resteasy

I recently rebuilt my Maven WAR Project because the HTTP requests were received, but no dependencies were to be found in the lib folder.
I then moved all the files I had created (classes, web.xml, ...) from the old to the new project. Now all dependencies are loaded, but I always get "HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL" (status 405) as a response to POST requests (on GET I get 404 etc.).
In the meantime I've gone through many tutorials again to see if I've forgotten something, but I just can't find what my mistake is.
I use Wildfly, RESTEasy and Eclipse.
Below are a few files that could possibly contain my error

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="4.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd">
</web-app>
```

jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd">
    <context-root>/xyz</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

MyApplication.java

```
package com.xyz.util.rest;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

import com.xyz.employee.rest.EmployeeRest;

@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
        classes.add(EmployeeRest.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

EmployeeRest.java

```
package com.xyz.employee.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.xyz.employee.EmployeeAndPassword;
import com.xyz.employee.service.EmployeeService;
import com.xyz.employee.service.dto.EmployeeDTO;
import com.xyz.servicelocator.ServiceLocator;

@Path("/employee")
public class EmployeeRest {
    EmployeeService emplServ = ServiceLocator.locateService(EmployeeService.class);

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/create")
    public Response createEmployee(EmployeeAndPassword emplAndPwd) {

        return Response.ok(emplServ.createEmployee((EmployeeDTO) emplAndPwd, emplAndPwd.getPassword())).build();
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>XYZ</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>12</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>12</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.22.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20200518</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.13.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>xyz</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

I tried to send a request to this url via postman: http://localhost:8080/xyz/rest/employee/create

Comment: You should mark several of these dependencies as `<scope>provided</scope>` as they are provided by the server. It's possible there is a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I've replaced RESTEasy and Wildfly with Jersey and Tomcat. Now it works without problems

But I don't know why RESTEasy and Wildfly didn't worked...

Answer (score 0):

The following dependency will clash with wildfly:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.22.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Add the scope as provided to resolve the problem, or better remove it.